# Identity Server 3 token validation

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

How can we validate token generated from another client, on mobile if the app has link which passes token to the website, that website has some controller which accept token , how to authenticate user with access_token?

Is there a method in identity server 3 which validate access_token?

Comment: this endpoint might help..  [link](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/accessTokenValidation.html)

Comment: thanks @Immanuel it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in endpoint in indentityserver 3 which validate token, it can be called using GET or post by passing token and the response status code can tell if it is valid or not.

[more information](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/accessTokenValidation.html)

Also, it can be validated using JwtSecurityTokenHandler (). ValidateToken () method. it will ClaimsPrincipal.